# Dispatcher function never gets called in React thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a project in React, but there's an issue I can't resolve with using Redux. My thunk is set up as follows

```
    export const getData = async () => {

      return async(dispatch) => {

        const sendRequest = async () => {

            const url = '...';
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            return data;
        }

        try {
            const myData = await sendRequest();
            console.log(myData)

            dispatch(dataActions.setData(myData))   
        }

        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }

}
```

On the other hand, my slice looks like this

```
const initialState = {
    my_data: []
};

const dataSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'data',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setData(state, action){

            state.my_data = action.payload.myData;
        }
    }
})

export const dataActions = dataSlice.actions;
export default dataSlice.reducer;
```

In my App.js, I call it with the following code

```
const data = useSelector((state)=>{return state.data.my_data})

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(getData);
  }, [dispatch])
```

I used a number of `console.log()`s in order to find out where the issue might be and I found that it does, in fact, enter the `getData()` function, but it never touches what's being returned. I even tried making a `dispatcher()` function which contained the code that's being returned, but it would only get called if I called it inside of `getData()` and it would give me the following error - 'TypeError: dispatch is not a function at ...'

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke getData while dispatching in order for the thunk action creator to be called.

```
   useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(getData());
  }, [dispatch])
```

Comment: Once I did, I got this error -> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions. See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware and https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware for examples.

Comment: how have you created your store